# Insert into *table name* select *function call* doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use a custom function to get a multiplication of two numbers and insert the result into the table column but I get an error:

**Result consisted of more than one row**

Code where I run into trouble:

```
INSERT INTO receipt(drug, amount, sum)
SELECT clientele.drug, clientele.amount, CalculateSum(clientele.amount, smallestprice.price)
FROM clientele, smallestprice
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

CalculateSum function source code:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
USE pharmacydb;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateSum(amount INT, price DECIMAL)
    RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum DECIMAL;
    DECLARE local_otc BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE local_amount INT;
    SELECT otc FROM drug INTO local_otc;
    SELECT amount FROM clientele INTO local_amount;
    SET sum = 0;
    IF local_otc = true THEN
        SET sum = amount * price;
    ELSEIF local_amount < amount THEN
        SET sum = local_amount * price;
    ELSE
        SET sum = amount * price;
    END IF;
    RETURN sum;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: And what about sample data, as I also mentioned? If it's talking about multiple rows being the problem we need to see that. We cannot know how many rows a query will return unless we see related data. I'd guess either one or both of `SELECT otc FROM drug INTO local_otc;
    SELECT amount FROM clientele INTO local_amount;`...I can only speculate without seeing data but it seems unlikely you would only have one row in a table called "drug", for example. Surely you need a WHERE clause there to identify a specific row fromt the table which is relevant at that moment?

Comment: To be honest though I would think you don't actually need a function here, maybe a CASE statement and some proper joins between your tables would do the job. (I think that even if you fix the function you are going to discover a problem with the FROM clause of the main query after that. Now would be a great time to learn how to use INNER JOIN correctly

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, one (or both) of the two SELECT INTOs in your function's code return more than one result. SELECT INTO expressions can only return one row. Which `drug` and `clientele` are you trying to get the respective `otc` and `amount` values from?